# To what extent would my nationality and my research topic impact my chance to get research grants in the UK?

Tags: funding, united-kingdom

As a new lecturer in a UK university, I am willing to apply for an EPSRC "First Investigator Award". The (STEM) topic I have in mind is kind of related to autonomous nuclear operations. I have initially decided to write about this as it may maximize my chance since

- I have a solid research record in robotics;
- I had worked as a safety-critical systems engineer in railway industry, and I found myself a fan of safety culture for engineering products;
- my university has solid infrastructure in this field and hosts a well-known research institute totally involved in such topics. So, I can get recommendation letters from them to support my application.

But a potential problem is that I am originally from a country that has a terrible relationship with the West (including the UK) in almost any context such as energy and nuclear concerns. Now, I am skeptical whether or not this issue would single-handedly lead to the rejection of my grant proposal just because of national security concerns regardless of its research merits.

So, does any body know what the assessment routines are associated with the involvement of international PIs in the research tied with sensitive sectors in the UK? I obviously don't expect to get an answer with full details of what really happens in practice behind the scene. What I hope to catch is a rough feeling of how detrimentally that problem may impact my chance for the success (given the fact that I can only apply once for this grant).

(I already asked this question from my university authorities, and as expected, they left it unanswered.)

Comment: As a bit of a nitpick, I find the "willing to apply" phrasing which I think may come from Indian English to be quite off-putting to a US or UK speaker. "Willing" sounds like you are somehow giving something up or offering to do something, like a chore, whereas an application is typically for something that a lot of people want and you are competing to get.

Comment: I just wanted to point out something potentially embarrassing in the language used, as the word has a different meaning to many readers than you might guess from a dictionary. It doesn't seem good to me to revert the edit suggestion someone else made. Also I don't think you know what "spamming" means...

Comment: @User: please note our [code of conduct](https://academia.stackexchange.com/conduct): the users here are trying to help you; accusing them of "spamming" and wasting their time is unacceptable.

Comment: Somewhat related https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/185922/security-clearance-for-a-dual-like-naturalized-u-s-citizen/185969#185969

Comment: @schrödingcöder: That question assumes that a clearance process exists in that case, and the OP asked his chance for success. However, my question is essentially about the existence of such clearance routine related to my situation (since if there is any, I have no doubt that I will be rejected!). As another point, neither I am a Russian citizen nor the country of residence is US.